# Updating airgaped Azure devops git repository from a local git folder

Tags: git, azure-devops, version-control

I am working with some air-gaped systems and as part of the deployment, I need to update the sources for an external git repository to one of the Azure Devops on-premise air-gaped repository. First time I extracted the source and did the following.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin <url to the air-gaped Azure devops empty repository>
git push -u origin --all
```

I want to update it with new source changes but I am not sure how to go about it. Should I just overwrite the local directory with the update source and do the same as before ? I just don't want to mess things up. What is a better way do this over and over again in Azure devops.

Comment: What do you mean by "air-gapped"? (I interpret that phrase as "no network connection at all", which would mean your updates would involve physical media.)

Comment: @JimRedmond  No access to to other networks (internet). Yes, I copy and carry over these files in a usb flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with `git bundle create`.  This creates a repository bundle that you can transfer to the remote machine, and fetch from as if it were a repository.

Once you've transferred the archive, you can do `git bundle verify` on the bundle file and then simply fetch or pull from it as normal.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need file histories - just the contents of the repo at a particular commit or tag - then `git archive` could work pretty well here.

From a system that has access to the repo in question,

```
git archive -o /path/to/USB/drive/repo.zip HEAD
```

This builds a ZIP file at the named location (`/path/to/USB/drive/repo.zip`) of the full repository contents as of the latest commit (`HEAD`). You can do a tarball (change `.zip` to `.tar.gz`) or use a specific tag or commit (change `HEAD` to the tag name or the commit hash).

Comment: What is the proper way to update at the other end from the archive ? The same git commands that I used above ?. Won't it mess up the old source in the Azure devops repository ?

Comment: `git archive` just makes a ZIP file or tarball (or whatever other format you specify) of the repository contents at a given revision. It doesn't affect the repo itself, either on your system or elsewhere. As for updating the air-gapped systems, you'd get the files on there via sneakernet, unzip the file created by `git archive`, and then do whatever unspecified things are necessary to make the new code work.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear enough. Oh the isolated network, I have an Azure devops repository. I have pushed an old copy from the archive there. Should I just used the same git commands as before or do I need to do anything different ?

Comment: If you want to maintain history, then the accepted answer (using `git bundle`) will update it. My answer assumes that you're more interested in the contents of the repo, rather than the commit history; if you bring the output of `git archive` to the isolated network then you would not need to run any git commands whatsoever (just `unzip` or whatever the OS has).